# jQuery 'fluent' slide

Tags: jquery, slide

I'm using jQuery to slide some random text. This text will appear when one puts mouse over image, but the image (which triggers the slide) does not go with this text - in my case is 'plus image'. So let me explain on this example:

[image]

And I want it to be like this (plus goes with text at time of slide):

[image]

My code:

```
<div style="">
    <a href="java script:void(0)"><img style="float:left;" id="dodaj_obrazek_4" src="imgs/add.png" onmouseover="wys_obrazek(4)"></a>
    <div style="float: left; display: none;" id="dodaj_obr_4">
        <a onmouseout="sch_obrazek(4)" style="color:#414040;" href="java script:void(0)">Dodaj obrazek</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Functions that trigger the slide:

```
function wys_obrazek(liczba) {
    if ($('#dodaj_obr_' + liczba).is(':hidden')) {
        $('#dodaj_obr_' + liczba).show('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function sch_obrazek(liczba) {
    if ($('#dodaj_obr_' + liczba).is(':visible')) {
        $('#dodaj_obr_' + liczba).hide('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000);
    }
}​
```

Comment: So what's the problem or question?

Comment: Float them to the right instead of the left.

Comment: Floating them to right does not work, I want the image to be on the left side of text. The queston is - what should I change in code to make it work like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lWMTr.png

Comment: Float them to the right, but swap the image and the text round.

Comment: I swapped it and the nothing happened:(

Comment: @WojtekWątor You wish for the image and text to slide in at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is JQuery is animating them sequentially one option would be to wrap all components like so:

```
    <div style="width:500px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="dodaj_obrazek_wrap_4">
       <a href="java script:void(0)"><img style="float:left;" id="dodaj_obrazek_4" src="imgs/add.png"></a>
       <div style="float: left;" id="dodaj_obr_4">
          <a style="color:#414040;" href="java script:void(0)">Dodaj obrazek</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>​
```

Then the JQuery Changes to.

```
function wys_obrazek(liczba) {
    var item = $('#dodaj_obrazek_wrap_' + liczba);
    if (item.is(':hidden')) {
        item.animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt( item.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
            item.outerWidth() : 0 });
    }
}

function sch_obrazek(liczba) {
    var item = $('#dodaj_obrazek_wrap_' + liczba);
    if (item.is(':visible')) {
       item.animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt( item.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        item.outerWidth() : 0
    });
    }
}
```

As an example see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X286T/1/)

**UPDATE**

I could not find reference of using slide in hide/show so I added one myself.

Comment: ok but there is one problem - look
Image is visible, text is not visible - you put both of them into #dodaj_obrazek_wrap_xx - so it is visible, then you trigger it with
wys_obrazek
and this condition: 
"if ($('#dodaj_obrazek_wrap_' + liczba).is(':hidden')) {"
 is always false. When I removed this condition the script still does not work at all.

Comment: @WojtekWątor I couldn't find slide in the properties for show/hide so i provided a different one also take a look at the fiddle i provided a fiddle as example